# What is this 'OBL'?

Tags: notation, construction-grammar

I'm reading Goldberg's *Constructions* and find her employing the symbol 'OBL' to represent a category of syntactic constituent.

> SUBJ OBL OBJ

I take it that 'OBL' is read 'oblique' in some sense; but I am puzzled to understand exactly what sense, since it seems to embrace both preposition phrases and adjective phrases (*e.g.* 'OBL<sub>PP/AP</sub>'), standing in for what I would categorize as adjectival and locative predicate complements. I have found no instance where 'OBL' is realized as a nominal, and it's not the *object* of a preposition, so it doesn't appear to be an *oblique object* in either of the senses I'm familiar with.

Can anyone provide a name and definition for this symbol? And for lagniappe, can anyone tell me how folks who use this symbol represent a nominal predicate complement?

Answer (score 2):

Arguments that are neither subject nor object nor adjunct are obliques. For example, indirect objects and causees are obliques. They are usually indexed by θ roles.

Comment: This appears to be exactly what I want. Just to make sure, though: in this use, the bolded terms in these sentences would all be properly named "obliques"? -- *Barack Obama was elected **president***. *My car is **black***. *We painted the living room **blue***. *I put my keys **on the table***. *He was eventually found **by the forest rangers***.

Comment: @StoneyB In the second sentence "blue" is a nominal predicate. In the first sentence "president" is a secondary object. In most languages it would be an oblique though.

Comment: In other words, it's not a very useful term :)

Comment: @curiousdannii It is useful and well-established.

Comment: Hmm ... then your use does *not* sort with Goldberg's. in Goldberg, Recipients and Beneficiaries expressed as indirect objects are OBJ; only those expressed as PP are OBL. In Goldberg, *blue* **is** an OBL. I don't know how she would designate *president*; the construction doesn't arise in this book.

Comment: @StoneyB "My" definition of OBL comes from LFG. Moreover whether something is an OBL or not is language-specific. It seems that as with other linguistic terms, the definition depends on the theory used.

Comment: I'm all too conscious of context-sensitive terminology! :} In fact, what I'm trying to do is pin down how CG (or BCG, or perhaps proto-BCG) uses this term.

Comment: I disagree - what's useful about having a specific term for an argument that isn't one of two arguments that are arbitrarily excluded?

Comment: _Oblique_ is a term that's been in use for a long time. The literal meaning is "off at an angle" -- something that doesn't fit naturally into a rectangular paradigm -- and that's how people use it. If they have a theory to push, like Goldberg, then the term may well come to have a specialized use in that theory. But to say something is oblique is to say it's not very important, like the disposable agent in a passive.